# Aligning text and tikzpicture inside tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tcolorbox

I was wondering if I could insert some drawings in my examples with some text around them, just like this:

[image]

I've tried two different ways but none of them worked. My first approach was by using 'wrapfigure' and my second one inserting the text inside a '\node':

Results:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{exx}{EXAMPLE}{
    fonttitle=\bfseries, fontupper=\normalsize,
    theorem style=standard,
    enhanced,frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm+1pt,bottomtitle=-0.1cm+0.5em,
    bottomrule=1pt,
    colback=white,coltitle=red!75!black,
    title style=white,
    titlerule=1pt, titlerule style=red!75!black,
    borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{red!75!black}
}{exx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math, positioning, arrows.meta} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}        
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}}{}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{exx}{$\mathbb{R}^3$ curve}{}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> ={Straight Barb[line width=1pt, length=1mm]}]
\begin{axis}[view={-20}{-15}, axis lines=center,axis on top,
                xlabel=$y$,ylabel=$x$,zlabel=$z$,
                xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
                no marks,
                xmin=-1.5,xmax=2,ymin=-1,ymax=1.5,zmin=0,zmax=23]
                
                \addplot3+ [->, blue, domain=0:5*pi/9,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
                \addplot3+ [->, blue, domain=5*pi/9:12.8,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
                \addplot3+ [blue, domain=12.8:6*pi,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
                \node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill=blue, inner sep=1.3pt] at (0,1,0){};
                \node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill=blue, inner sep=1.3pt] at (0,1,6*pi){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

We have $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t)$ with $t\in[0,2k\pi]$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, blablablabla blabla blablabla blablabla.\\

When $k=3$, we obtain the following blabla bla blablabla:
\end{exx}

\begin{exx}{$\mathbb{R}^3$ curve}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[> ={Straight Barb[line width=1pt, length=1mm]}]
\begin{axis}[view={-20}{-15}, axis lines=center,axis on top,
                xlabel=$y$,ylabel=$x$,zlabel=$z$,
                xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
                no marks,
                xmin=-1.5,xmax=2,ymin=-1,ymax=1.5,zmin=0,zmax=23]
                
                \addplot3+ [->, blue, domain=0:5*pi/9,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
                \addplot3+ [->, blue, domain=5*pi/9:12.8,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
                \addplot3+ [blue, domain=12.8:6*pi,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
                \node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill=blue, inner sep=1.3pt] at (0,1,0){};
                \node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill=blue, inner sep=1.3pt] at (0,1,6*pi){};
                
                \node [left, align=flush left, xshift=2cm, yshift=0.3cm, text width=6cm] at (current bounding box.west) {We have $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t)$ with $t\in[0,2k\pi]$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, blablablabla blabla blablabla blablabla.\\
                
                When $k=3$, we obtain the following blabla bla blablabla:};
                
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exx}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a side by side `tcolorbox` for your theorem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{exx}{EXAMPLE}{
  fonttitle=\bfseries, fontupper=\normalsize,
  theorem style=standard,
  sidebyside, lower separated=false, sidebyside align=top seam,
  enhanced, frame hidden,
  boxrule=0pt,
  left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm, toptitle=0.1cm+1pt,bottomtitle=-0.1cm+0.5em,
  bottomrule=1pt,
  colback=white,coltitle=red!75!black,
  title style=white,
  titlerule=1pt, titlerule style=red!75!black,
  borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{red!75!black}
}{exx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{exx}{$\mathbb{R}^3$ curve}{}
  We have $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t)$ with $t\in[0,2k\pi]$ and
  $k\in\mathbb{N}$, …

  \medskip
  
  When $k=3$, we obtain the following …

  \tcblower

  \begin{tikzpicture}[> ={Straight Barb[line width=1pt, length=1mm]}]
    \begin{axis}[view={-20}{-15}, axis lines=center,axis on top,
      xlabel=$y$,ylabel=$x$,zlabel=$z$,
      xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
      no marks,
      xmin=-1.5,xmax=2,ymin=-1,ymax=1.5,zmin=0,zmax=23]

      \addplot3+ [->, blue, domain=0:5*pi/9,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
      \addplot3+ [->, blue, domain=5*pi/9:12.8,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
      \addplot3+ [blue, domain=12.8:6*pi,samples=100,samples y=0] ({sin(deg(x))},{cos(deg(x))},{x});
      \node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill=blue, inner sep=1.3pt] at (0,1,0){};
      \node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill=blue, inner sep=1.3pt] at (0,1,6*pi){};

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{exx}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]